# Quebrar linha em links

Tags: html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um site mobile e estou com um problema, quando eu tenho um link muito grande (sem espaços ou '-' hifens), ele não "quebra" e vaza do layout. Existe uma forma de arrumar isso?

Comment: Você já tentou definir um width para a div? Coloque o código aqui, fica mais fácil para analisar.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade `word-wrap` para manipular a quebra de palavras

```css
p.test {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p class="test"> This paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>
```

### ou

```css
#div1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#div2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<p>As duas divs coném um texto muito lonbgo que não cabe na caixa, como você pode ver o texto é cortado</p>

<p>Essa div usa "text-overflow:clip":</p>
<div id="div1">Este é apenas um looongo texto que não cabe na caixa</div>

<p>Essa div usa "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<div id="div2">Este é apenas um looongo texto que não cabe na caixa</div>
```